# Combining javascript prototype styles

Tags: javascript, prototype-chain

Is it possible to combine the following

```
function something() {}
function somethingElse() {}

somethingElse.prototype = new something();
somethingElse.prototype.someFunction = function() {}
...
```

with this

```
somethingElse.prototype = {
    someFunction: function() {},
    ...
}
```

and maintain the prototype-inheritance-chain

It is purely cosmetic I guess.  I would just like to define all the functions inside {} rather then using a vast amount of ...prototype... = ...

I have seen quite a lot of either but never them brought together.

Comment: I've tried various things like setting __proto__ afterward etc.  The __proto__ was pretty funky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My personal favorite approach to this is to grab the underscore.js library. It's got a really nice method called extend to tack properties onto objects. So, I can do:

```
function something() {}
function somethingElse() {}

somethingElse.prototype = new something();

_.extend(somethingElse.prototype, {
    someFunction: function () { },
    someOtherFunction: function () { }
});
```

Comment: I'll have to go with this.  It isn't the solution I was really looking for but it does do it.  Looking in the underscore source it is pretty much just copying all the objects you are passing in.  So it sounds fairly slow.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is, in the second version, `somethingElse` instances will not inherit anything from `something` and its prototype chain. Considering your example code, that wouldn't make any difference, though.

Comment: It matters if `instanceof` is important.

Comment: That was the whole point.  The second part cannot get any inherit chain action going on.  Chris's extend would do the job.  I was hoping for something that didn't need to be included.

Comment: @0xFADE Apparently I missed your "and maintain the prototype-inheritance-chain" sentence...

Answer (score 0):

Well, they're quite the same indeed.

```
foo = {}
foo.bar = baz
```

is the same as

```
foo = {
    bar: baz
}
```

It's a matter of taste.

BTW : it is considered better style to name constructors (anything to be called with new) with a capital initial, to differentiate it from regular functions, because confusing them could do very bad things.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.defineProperties`, but it's actually more verbose, and doesn't have support in legacy browsers:

```
Object.defineProperties(somethingElse.prototype,{
    someOtherFunction: {
        value:function() {...}
    },
    ...
});
```

Alternatively, you could add a rudimentary `extend` method to the Object prototype:

```
Object.prototype.extend = function(obj){
    for(var p in obj)this[p] = obj[p];
};
```

Which will allow you to do this:

```
somethingElse.prototype.extend({
    A:function(){'a'},
    B:function(){'b'}
});
```

I would generally recommend against this as modifying the prototypes of native objects can get dicey.

Comment: Thanks.  I wonder if the opposite is possible.  Instead of doing all this to copy the objects is there a way to set the prototype accurately when you generate it.
    obj.prototype = {
        ...
        _something_that_defines_the_prototype: new something()
    }